# nextjs custom serve directory in production

Tags: build, next.js

The problem: When I run `next build` on my production server, the page is served unstyled while building.
What I want to do:

1. build the app to `build` directory
2. move `build` to `build-public`
3. serve the app from `build-public`.

I don't want to setup a custom server for that simple task.

My `package.json` `scripts` section:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev -p 3002",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start -p 3002"
  },
```

My `next.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  basePath: '',
  distDir: 'build', // dir to build
  dir: 'build-public', // serve from build-public. 'Dir' option is not working.
}
```

Comment: The `dir` option does not exist, did you mean to use [`basePath`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/basepath) instead?

Comment: basePath is for links. If `dir` option not exists, what is the solution then?

Comment: Can you clarify why do you need to move the built app from `build` to `build-public`? Why not just name the build folder `build-public`?

Comment: Because build process takes around 2 minutes. While these 2 minutes, the site content left unstyled

Comment: @VictorGorban Have you found a solution for this? I am also struggling with same issue.

Comment: @VivekPalanisamy looks like direct solution is impossible. I now use a cache strategy, which is actually dumb for such a robust solution.

Comment: @VivekPalanisamy you can check the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*tl/dr: see paragraph 3.*

1. **replace next.config.js between build and serve** Next.js uses `distDir` config option as the server directory, each time it launches a script.
   So, if I build my app with `distDir` set to `build`, then I get my bundle inside `build` directory.
   Next I change `distDir` to `build-public, and run` next start`, so my project is served from` build-public`.

**next.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
...
  distDir: 'build' // build to 'build' directory. Then change distDir to 'build-public', so it will serve from 'build-public'.
...
}
```

2. **serve from nested directory** I can run `next serve ./build-public`, and Nextjs will search for the app build inside `./build-public/build`. So, after `next build` I need to move `build` folder to `build-public/build` and run `next serve ./build-public`.

**package.json**

```
...
"scripts": {
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start ./nested-dir -p 3011"
  },
...
```

3. **export a function in next.config.js**. See more advanced example here:
   [nextjs-examples](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-env-from-next-config-js/next.config.js)

**next.config.js**

```
const {
  PHASE_PRODUCTION_BUILD,
  PHASE_PRODUCTION_SERVER,
} = require("next/constants");

module.exports = (phase) => {
  let distDir = "";
  if (phase == PHASE_PRODUCTION_BUILD) {
    distDir = "build";
  } else if (phase == PHASE_PRODUCTION_SERVER) {
    distDir = "build-public";
  }

  return {
    ... 
    distDir,
    ....
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use an environment variable in next.config.js and set that environment variable before you run the build command:

```js
    // next.config.js

    module.exports = {
      distDir: process.env.BUILD_DIR || 'build-public',
    }
```

```js
    // package.json
    
    "scripts": {
      "build": "BUILD_DIR=build next build",
    }
```

Comment: Another one. I want to SERVE from different directory. Build to directory1, make som custom adjustments, serve from directory2.

Comment: This does exactly what you’re asking for. Build to "build" and then SERVE from "build-public". What do you mean by "Another one"?

Comment: because nextjs builds and serves the same directory. Your answer's code does the same. https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/setting-a-custom-build-directory

Comment: I don't know, logic says that your solution must work, but it doesn't.